# How do I set the time under which user can delete or update it?

Tags: django, time, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-haystack

I have model Order

```
class Order(models.Model):
STATUS = (
    ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
)
shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.CASCADE, null=True)
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.CASCADE, null=True)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.CASCADE, null=True)
quantity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, )
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS, default='Pending')
note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
```

How do I create it? If the user is  customer then they delete or update under the 5 minutes of order, if the user is shop then they can update or delete any time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of

`auto_now_add=True`:

For DateTimeField:

```
from django.utils import timezone

date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
```

Comment: but how I set the time of update or delete for customer

Comment: What do u want to delete or update ? the date_created or the order instance ?

Comment: I want to delete or update **ORDER** under the 5minutes of the time means if order created at  **4:00 pm** then the user.customer delete it or update it under the **4:05 pm**